# View - Group by Managed Metadata field

Tags: view, mms

I have users in the contribute group and they are seeing Region: null(4) in the library view. The site collection admin can see a view with Region: SW(4) which is group by region (region is a managed metadata single value and not multiple value).

The end user can edit properties and able to see managed metadata (meaning available for tagging is working) and select a value and save the document. Even all items view does not show the MMS values for Region column for contribute users. What am I missing?

Comment: Check the permissions in the list "TaxonomyHiddenList"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer from the following blog.

https://prashobjp.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/managed-metadata-column-values-not-visible-for-users-in-sharepoint-20132010/

I am not sure what happened but I added nt authority\all authenticated users and now everything is working.